# How to convert object to JSON in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapping, aws-api-gateway, apache-velocity

I have some simple data I want to transform with API Gateway:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"id":"1", "name":"Foo"},
        {"id":"2", "name":"Bar"},
        {"id":"3", "name":"Dead"},
        {"id":"4", "name":"Beef"}
    ]
}
```

I'm able to loop the data:

```
#foreach($elem in $input.path('$.data'))
    {
       "Data": $elem,
       "Foo": "Bar"
    }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
```

The **expected** result is:

```
{"Data": {"id":"1", "name":"Foo"}, "Foo": "Bar"},
{"Data": {"id":"2", "name":"Bar"}, "Foo": "Bar"},
{"Data": {"id":"3", "name":"Dead"}, "Foo": "Bar"},
{"Data": {"id":"4", "name":"Beef"}, "Foo": "Bar"}
```

However, the **actual** result is:

```
{"Data": {id=1, name=Foo}, "Foo": "Bar"},
{"Data": {id=2, name=Bar}, "Foo": "Bar"},
{"Data": {id=3, name=Dead}, "Foo": "Bar"},
{"Data": {id=4, name=Beef}, "Foo": "Bar"}
```

`$elem` produces `{id=1, name=Foo}` which seems to be what the objects are stringified as. I'd like to have it in JSON, how to I accomplish that?

I've tried `$elem.stringify()`, `$input.json($elem)` and `$elem.json()` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with an odd work-around reading about the `$index` and how Apache Velocity works:

```
#foreach($elem in $input.path('$.data'))
    #set($pathBegin = "$.data[")
    #set($pathEnd = "]")
    #set($currentIndex = $foreach.index)
    #set($thePath = "$pathBegin$currentIndex$pathEnd")
    #set($elemJson = $input.json($thePath)) 
  {
    "Data": $elemJson,
    "Foo": "Bar"
  }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
```

This could probably be more optimised but it actually works and prints out the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This was what I was looking for. How can it be that this is the correct way to reverse a json object back to a json string. You could make this a oneliner when taking the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493056/1118905) into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

addiction to Mikael Dúi Bolinder ans

if you need JSON Stringyfy

just use

```
"$util.escapeJavascript($elemJson)"
```